# Community promotion ad to run on other SE’s

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Stack Exchange sites that have graduated run so-called “Community Promotion Ads”: these run in the right sidebar of each page, and are designated according to votes on the Meta of each site. For example, see [on Physics.SE](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/980/community-promotion-ads-2012) how it works.

The good thing about these ads is that the new visitors they bring are, for the most part, already users on other Stack Exchange sites, and they now how the system works. Over at [Chemistry](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com), we have [placed an ad on Physics.SE](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1334/91) and it does bring us some traffic.

**I’d like to propose that we come up with an ad to run on our sibling SE sites**. I see three points to deal with:

- finding a nice motto or a catchy sentence
- creating the ad itself (having a nice graphics improves one’s click-through rate, but it's not absolutely necessary)
- coming up with a list of sites we want to target: I’m thinking [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/), [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/), [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/), [TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/), [English L&U](http://english.stackexchange.com), [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) (sorted roughly in decreasing order of suitability IMO)

What do you think?

Comment: Added to site bulletin for a week.

Answer (score 7):

**Edit:** second version incorporating Daniel’s suggestion

[image]

Comments very welcome!

Comment: This looks pretty good, but needs Academia SE as you say. Maybe "... but academia.se has answers"

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of academics over at tex.sx, I wonder if we could get someone to help design us a coat of arms. It might be useful also when we graduate. I would be happy to use some of my tex.sx rep to offer a 500 rep bounty.

I have asked: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79147/draw-a-coat-of-arms-in-latex

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'll add an answer to keep track of the other sites’ meta where ads were posted for voting. **Please go there and upvote!**

- [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1571/91) (now running; check stats [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/980))
- [Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6441/3406) (now running; check stats [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3278))
- [English L&U](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3235/3479) (now running; check stats [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2223))
- [TeX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2840/3734) (now running; check stats [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2046))
- [Mathematica](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/812/700) (now running; check stats [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/577))

Answer (score -1):

It's a good idea to plan. But the problem is technically we haven't graduated yet. We're still in beta mode. We need to get the number of questions up a little higher. (About 15%, if my math is right.)

Comment: The ads are displayed on graduated sites, but they can be ads for anything: other SE sites (graduated or not), even non-SE websites (see the Physics examples).

Comment: Okay. I misunderstood your intent—you want to create an ad that can be advertised on Physics.SE (and perhaps Math.SE, etc.). I had thought you wanted the ads here. Still not a bad idea to plan here, though.