# Community ads for 2013

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Last year, we managed to get a [nice campaign of community ads](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/238/2700) to run on other sites of the Stack Exchange network (Physics, Mathematics, English L&U, TeX and Mathematica). But every year, the voting starts anew, and we need to gather votes in these communities’ Meta sites for our ad to run:

- [Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8196/3406)
- [English L&U](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3625/3479)
- [CSTheory](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2639/8030)
- [TeX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3179/3734) (ad is now running)
- [Mathematica](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/865/700) (ad is now running)
- [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2813/91) (ad is now running)

If you're a member of these communities, please follow the links above and upvote the ad!

Comment: Also, the list of sites and the ad image are not set in stone: if you feel that we should advertise on another site, please edit the post above. If you want to suggest a new ad image, post it as an answer below!